# Using QSqlQuery::bindValue() for variable number of placeholders

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am familiar with the simple use of `QSqlQuery::prepare()` and `QSqlQuery::bindValue()` as in:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT name, address FROM members WHERE id = :id");
query.bindValue(":id", member_id);
query.exec();
```

In this scenario I show a list of people (members) to the user, all with a check-box in front. The user can simply check which members to delete.
So now, the number of `:id` are variable.

Currently, I solve this issue in quite a untidy fashion. All the id's checked people will be put in an array of integers called `checked_items_ids` and then I simply for-loop that array:

```
QString prepare_query = QString("DELETE FROM members WHERE id = ").append(checked_items_ids[0]);

for(int i = 1; i < checked_items_ids.count(); i++)
    prepare_query.append(QString(" OR id = %1").arg(checked_items_ids[i]));

QSqlQuery query(prepare_query);
query.exec();
```

Is there a 'tidier' way to do this? Using `bindValue()` or anything that I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not the expert for `QSqlQuery`, so my answer might be slightly off the mark. I see nothing wrong in not using `prepare()` and `bindValue()`. It also seems to me a bit "odd" to use these in a `DELETE` statement. As I said, I'm not the expert on this, there may be other guys that can shed some light on this aspect.

I see two cosmetic issues:

1. the way you use `checked_items_ids`, first time with null argument, second time iterating. A `QStringList` can help in constructing the SQL statement.
2. setting the SQL statement in the constructor. Setting it in the `exec()` function might be more "natural".

These are cosmetic issues only. They do, however, improve readability of your code.

```
QStringList querylist;
for(auto id : checked_items_ids)
    querylist << QString("id = %1").arg(id);
QString querystring = QString("DELETE FROM members WHERE ") +
                  querylist.join(" OR ");

QSqlQuery query;
query.exec(querystring);
```